# how to put mean lines in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am try to do a plot whith means lines by group (in ggplot), and i have my code like this

```
ggplot(gama, aes(x = distancia, y= glipidoscmtejido, colour= estado)) + 
geom_point(position=position_dodge(.5), alpha= 1, size=3) +
geom_crossbar(data=gama,aes(x=distancia,ymin=mean(glipidoscmtejido), 
ymax=mean(glipidoscmtejido),y=mean(glipidoscmtejido),colour=estado), width = 0.5)
```

and I get this

[image]

but i need the mean line by distancia and by estado. how can i make it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this using `stat_summary` to plot the means per `estado` per `distancia`:

```
# Generate some sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    x = rnorm(100),
    estado = sample(c("sana", "lesionada"), 100, replace = T),
    distancia = sample(c("0-1", "2.5-3.5", "5.6"), 100, replace = T));

require(ggplot2);
ggplot(df, aes(x = distancia, y = x, colour = estado)) +
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
    stat_summary(
        fun.y = mean, 
        geom = "errorbar", 
        aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..), 
        position = position_dodge(width = 0.3), 
        width = 0.25);
```

[image]

Comment: it is possible to reduce the length of the line?

Comment: @victorpiñon You can adjust the width of the bar with e.g. `width = 0.25`, see my updated solution.

Comment: Great, glad to help @victorpiñon